# How do I redirect output from python to file

Tags: windows, python, cmd.exe, stdout, stderr

I want to redirect all output (stdout and stderr) of console to the text file. I make the following steps:

1. Open cmd.exe
2. Start command:

   "python.exe" > "file.txt"

After that, I'm waiting for the python's output in the file, but it's still in console. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You've forgotten to put the name of the Python program, something like:

`python.exe program.py > file.txt`

Comment: You need `> file.txt 2>&1` to get `stderr` as well as `stdout`

Comment: @Dominique, No. I haven't forgot. I want to work with python in interactive mode and send commands through console instead of writing script.

Comment: Have a look at this thread - there is much there, as it's a bit of a tricky thing.  And, the asker added comments to summarize what was useful for them.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947810/how-to-save-a-python-interactive-session

Comment: @condiosluzverde Great find, this may be a duplicate question... Unless... OP, is there a reason you are trying to do it via CMD vs this native Python method?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CMD.exe, you could use the Anaconda prompt.

In the Anaconda prompt, the code you described above works with the Python output going to a file and still being able to interact a the Python prompt.

[image: Anaconda prompt]

Tha Anaconda prompt does have a very similar look and behaviour as the CMD prompt.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993175/difference-between-command-prompt-and-anaconda-prompt)  has info on the difference between them.

Comment: Just tried it in Python 3.6.6 and the behaviour was the same on Windows 10 CMD. What version of Python and Windows are you using?